# How to get car vin info using Car API?

Tags: android-automotive

Im currently develop automotive application using car sdk. But cant get vin info from CarPropertyManager. So please give example to get car vi info using Car API

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Car object example `mCar` and call `mCar = Car.createCar(this);` when the application is loading.
2. Create a CarPropertyManager object example `mCarPropertyManager` and instantiate it by writing `mCarPropertyManager = car.getCarManager(Car.PROPERTY_SERVICE);`.
3. Create a listener for VIN information event as `vinCarPropertyListener`.
4. Register for any event. In your case, its Car VIN.
   `carPropertyManager.registerCallback(vinCarPropertyListener, VehiclePropertyIds.INFO_VIN)`
5. In `onEventChanged()`, you will receive the VIN as `CarPropertyValue`.

```kotlin
override fun onChangeEvent(value: CarPropertyValue<Any>) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Received on changed car property event")
       // value.value type changes depending on the vehicle property.
       Log.d(TAG, "VIN value: ${value.value}")
}
```

Reference link: [CarPropertyExample](https://github.com/android/car-samples/blob/main/car-lib/CarGearViewerKotlin/automotive/src/main/java/com/example/cargearviewer/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: Is it possible for Android Auto (not Automotive)?