# Android auto getting RPM data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-auto

Ive looked everywhere for a solution to read RPM data on Android Auto with Android studio. Found no solution. I was hoping someone has more experience in this field and could point me in the right direction.

I tried to use CarHardwareManager and looked into CarPropertyManager but I cannot find any proper documentation on how to implement an RPM listener of some sort.

My end goal is to have a listener that will receive the current RPM the vehicle is at.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Android Auto is for UI / media (or for car manufacturers). Automotive performance data will require third-party hardware and an app that supports OBD like https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD

Comment: @MorrisonChang that's incorrect: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/accessing-car-hardware-apis-in-your-app.html

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for the correction. Android Auto and Android Automotive OS branding confuses me.

Comment: Did you work out the answer to your question because I'm interested in the answer plus whatever it is you are working on

Answer (score 1):

There is this function that you can use to get properties.
[CarPropertyManager.getProperty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager#getProperty(int,%20int))

You need to use constants defined in `VehiclePropertyIds`. Here goes the one that could do the trick:
[VehiclePropertyIds.ENGINE_RPM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds#ENGINE_RPM). Note that this requires certains permissions.

Also the function seems to take a areaId argument. It's a little confusing but using `CarPropertyManager.getAreaId(ENGINE_RPM, VEHICLE_AREA_TYPE_WHEEL)` may yield the required value. Please double-check it as I cannot test it myself.

`CarPropertyManager.getProperty(propertyId, areaId)`. This should return a `CarPropertyValue`. Then you can use `getValue()`.

As for the listener, you may implemented this interface to listen for changes in such properties.
[CarPropertyManager.CarPropertyEventCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager.CarPropertyEventCallback)

`CarPropertyManager.registerCallback(callback, propertyId, refreshRate)`

I'll link to `registerCallback` documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager#registerCallback(android.car.hardware.property.CarPropertyManager.CarPropertyEventCallback,%20int,%20float)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How do i know which gradle dependency the CarPropertyManager is included in? I currently have... implementation 'androidx.car.app:app-automotive:1.2.0' but it does not include the CarPropertyManager. It seems that there is very little information on this topic online too. Google isn't bringing up any useful information on this.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it seems that there's few information about this topic. This post might be helpful on how to access CarPropertyManager. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65881218/19166078

Comment: It looks like only Android Automotive OS is able to receive the RPM data. However, there is an accelerometer within androidx.car which would give me similar data I could use. I would need to know when the driver lets off the gas pedal and trigger an event. Do you know of how I could possibly implement this?

Comment: Sorry. No, unfortunately I'm not sure you can replace RPM info with g-forces data from the accelerometer. I'm not a car technician nor a mechanical engineer but I think g-forces have not much to do with an engine RPM.